# Como otimizar tempo de carregamento de iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Tenho uma página com vários "iframes" do youtube que estão demorando consideravelmente para carregar.

[image: Foto:]

Gostaria de saber se é possível diminuir esse tempo de loading ou caso não seja possível, como colocar uma animação até que todos os vídeos sejam carregados.

Comment: poderia colocar parte do seu código para ajudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, seria possível diminuir o tempo de carregamento da página, você deve carregar apenas o que está visível na tela, os outros deixaria pra depois. Veja se o plugin Lazy load XT neste link ajuda você:

https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt

Sobre a animação, é bem simples e rápido de fazer, basta colocar uma imagem como background do seu iframe através de CSS.

http://codepen.io/dudaskank/pen/eBVpKw

## CSS

```css
iframe.loading {
  /* imagem from search on google :p */
  background: url(https://www.aiag.org/Content/images/admin_throbber.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

## HTML

```html
<iframe class='loading' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/Zi_XLOBDo_Y' />
```